# Removing Ubuntu and Installing Windows 7 [Step by Step]

Tags: ubuntu

I have **Ubuntu Saucy-Salamander 13.10**.I am not satisfied with it because there are software not compatible with Saucy-Salamander.I want to **remove Ubuntu Saucy-Salamander 13.10** and **install Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit**.Can provide me **Step by step** to remove Ubuntu and install Windows 7?

Comment: No need to remove Ubuntu if you want to blow it away . . . just pop the Win7 CD in, and when it's asking where to install, delete all the existing partitions, and install to the whole disk . . .

Answer (score 0):

Like the reply said.

1. Put in a windows disk and follow prompts
2. When it ask 'Where do you want to install Windows' click 'Drive options (advanced)'
3. Click 'Delete' till you only have Unallocated space left
4. Choose that Unallocated space.
5. Finish install